# Allow player to restart animation after it plays fully

Tags: unity, c#, animation

I have this code that plays an animation when the player touches the screen. The animation lasts 3 seconds.

```
public class canCDanim : MonoBehaviour  
{   
    public Animator anim;
    private void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();  
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {                
            anim.Play("CanReload");
        }
    }
}
```

The trouble is that if the player touches the screen again, the animation will not play again.

How can I make it so that I can restart the animation, but only after it's finished playing?

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please post an Answer below that explains *how* you solved it, so that other developers can learn from your experience.

Comment: @DMGregory Did something indicate they solved it? I was looking into this.

Comment: They posted an answer that simply said "I solved it" padded to meet the minimum character requirements. That doesn't really constitute an answer, so the post is hidden for now to save it from attracting excess down-votes. If they edit it to include their solution, we can restore it. I'm sure they and other users would be interested in your solution too, if you have something promising.